# How to substitute random numbers with words in a simple slot machine code

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to code a simple slot machine and instead of generating random numbers, I want the code to execute words like orange, apple, peach, pineapple when there is match. this is what I have so far, so any help is appreciated

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Project1Slot {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random random = new Random();
        int amount;
        int slot1;
        int slot2;
        int slot3;
        
        System.out.println("Enter the dollar amount here: ");
        amount = input.nextInt();
        
        slot1 = random.nextInt(2);
        slot2 = random.nextInt(2);
        slot3 = random.nextInt(2);
       
        System.out.println(slot1+"||"+slot2+"||"+slot3);
        
        // All Matches
        if (slot1==slot2 && slot2==slot3){
            System.out.println("Congratulations, you won " + "$" + 3 * amount);
        //if Two Matches
        }else if(slot1==slot2 || slot1==slot3 || slot2==3) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations,you won " + "$" + amount);    
        }else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, you lost");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just store the words in an array and use slot1, slot2, ... as index, e. g. `words[slot1]`.

Comment: the array gives me an error that 'it is not written to'

Comment: You'll have to define an array like `String[] words = {"banana", "orange", "apple"};`, then you can access the individual elements using an index, e. g. `System.out.println(words[slot1] + "||" + words[slot2] + "||" + words[slot3]);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example of how you can use a String[] Array or words for this sort of thing. **Read** the comments in code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Random random = new Random();
    
// Array of words for slot reels.
String[] words = {"Apple", "WILD", "Cherry", "Orange", "WILDx2", "Plum", 
                  "Banana", "WILDx3", "Melon", "Berry", "BONUS" ,"Lime" };
    
int amount;             // Wager amount.
int numberOfReels = 3;  // Number of slot reels to display.
    
String amt = "";        // Used for User Input and validation
// PROMPT - Loop again if entry is invalid/
while (amt.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.print("Enter the dollar amount here: -> ");
    amt = input.nextLine().trim();
        
    // If 'q' is supplied then quit.
    if (amt.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
        return;
    } 

    /* If the supplied string is not a numerical (integer) 
       value then inform User of Invalid Entry.        */
    if (!amt.matches("\\d+")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Dollar Amount! (" + amt 
                + ") Try again..." + System.lineSeparator());
        amt = "";   // Empty variable so to loop again.
    }
}
    
/* If we made it here, the entry is valid.
   Convert it to and int.            */
amount = Integer.parseInt(amt);
    
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");  // Use to build Reel String.
// Create a Reel String based on the number of slot reels...
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfReels; i++) {
    /* Append each random word from the words[] array 
       to sb. This will be done in a spaced format. */ 
    sb.append(String.format("%-12s", words[random.nextInt(words.length)]));
}
    
String reelString = sb.toString();
// Display the Slot Reel String in console.
System.out.println(reelString);
```